# Brackets: Custom Theme

Tags: json, github, less, adobe-brackets

I am trying to make a custom Brackets Theme. After I created a basic package.json file I went into extension manager to apply the theme so when editing the 'theme.less' file it would apply the fixes right away. Well my theme does not show up and I do have a package.json file and a theme.less file. The package.json code is:

```
{
    "name": “MyName.DarkPanja”,
    "title": “DarkPanja”,
    "description": “A Dark Theme By Panja“,
    "homepage": "https://github.com/Coler234/DarkPanja”,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": “MyName <myemail@provider.net> (https://github.com/Coler234/DarkPanja)”,
    "license": "MIT",
    "theme": {
        "file": "theme.less",
        "dark": true,
        "addModeClass": true
    },
    "keywords": ["theme"]
}
```

theme.less:

```
@background: #1d1f21;
@foreground: #ddd;
@hotpink: #CC0066;
@pinkpurple: #CC00FF;
@neongreen: #99FF00;

/* Code Styling */

.CodeMirror, .CodeMirror-scroll {
    background-color: @background;
    color: @foreground;
}

.CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
    background: #2f2f2f;
}

.show-line-padding .CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
    box-shadow: inset 15px 0 0 0 #000;
}

.CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline {
    .CodeMirror-gutter-elt {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        color: #fff;
    }
    .inline-widget .CodeMirror-gutter-elt {
        color: #767676;    
    }
}

.cm-atom, .cm-string, .cm-string-2, .cm-hr {color: @hotpink;}
.cm-number, .cm-attribute, .cm-plus {color: @pinkpurple;}
.cm-def, .cm-property {color: @neongreen;}
.cm-variable, .cm-variable-2, .cm-variable-3, .cm-operator, .cm-meta, .cm-bracket {color: @foreground;}
.cm-comment {color: #767676;}
.cm-error, .cm-minus {color: #dc322f;}
.cm-header {color: #d85896;}
.cm-link {color: @pinkpurple; text-decoration: none;}
.cm-rangeinfo {color: #656de8;}
.cm-keyword, .cm-qualifier, .cm-builtin, .cm-tag, .cm-quote {color: #656de8;}

/* Extra CSS */

.CodeMirror-searching {
    background-color: #660066;
    &.searching-current-match {
        background-color: #6600CC;
    }
}


.CodeMirror-cursor {
    border-left: 1px solid #c5c8c6 !important;
}

.CodeMirror-gutters {
    background-color: @background;
    border-right: none;
}

.CodeMirror-linenumber {
    color: #767676;
}

.CodeMirror .CodeMirror-selected {
    background: #333f48;
}
.CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-selected {
    background: #0099FF;
}

.CodeMirror-matchingbracket, .CodeMirror-matchingtag {
    /* Ensure visibility against gray inline editor background */
    background-color: #2e5c00;
    color: @foreground !important;
}

.CodeMirror-overwrite .CodeMirror-cursor {
    border-left: none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

/*
    CodeMirror's use of descendant selectors for certain styling causes problems when editors are
    nested because, for items in the inner editor, the left-hand clause in the selector will now
    match either the actual containing CodeMirror instance *OR* the outer "host" CodeMirror instance.
    TODO (issue #324): We'll still have problems if editors can be nested more than one level deep,
    or if any other descendant-selector-driven CM styles can differ between inner & outer editors
    (potential problem areas include line wrap and coloring theme: basically, anything in codemirror.css
    that uses a descandant selector where the CSS class name to the left of the space is something
    other than a vanilla .CodeMirror)
 */
.CodeMirror {
    .CodeMirror {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .CodeMirror .CodeMirror-gutters {
        background: transparent;
        border-right: none;
    }

    .CodeMirror .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .CodeMirror .CodeMirror-activeline .CodeMirror-gutter-elt {
        background: transparent;
        color: #767676;
    }

    .CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
        background: #2f2f2f;
    }

    .CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline {
        .CodeMirror-gutter-elt {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
}

.CodeMirror-foldgutter-open:after {
    color: #666;
}
.CodeMirror-foldgutter-folded:after {
    color: #aaa;
}

.CodeMirror.over-gutter, .CodeMirror-activeline {
    .CodeMirror-foldgutter-open:after {
        color: #888;
    }
}

.CodeMirror-foldmarker {
    border-color: #000;
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: #444;
}

/* Non-editor styling */

.image-view,
.not-editor {
    background-color: @background;
}

.view-pane .image-view {
    color: @foreground;
}
```

Both files are in a folder called 'DarkPanja' and located in Brackets/Extensions/User/DarkPanja. Because that didn't work I zip'ed it up dragged it in the extension manager in Brackets. That didn't work either so I uploaded it as a repository to GitHub and tried downloading it as a link:
https://github.com/Coler234/DarkPanja.
The .zip error is: Install/Update aborted due to the following errors:
Root to it(It is on a flash drive!): Unknown Internal Error.
The GitHub link says:
The package.json file is not valid (error was: SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use normal quotes (i.e. `"`) in JSON, otherwise it's not valid.
Right now, you're using special quotes for values like `“MyName.DarkPanja”`.

Comment: Thanks, I copied this from an online template so I guess that was an issue. THANKS!!!!